# Complexity of Multiple Binary Search and comparison algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, big-o

> Hello,
>
> I have two questions regarding complexity:
>
> 1) What would be the Best/worst complexity of a binary search called
>   multiple times. In other words a binary search used to compare two
>   arrays. I believe one of them is O(mlog(n)) (no matches between
>   arrays). However, since I can't figure out the other, I can't tell if
>   this is the best or worst.
>
> 2) For the following segment of code: Two arrays A of size m and B of
>   size n where m>=n, and where A and B have gone through a bubble sort
>   each. In addition no elements in A are repeated. And no elements in B
>   are repeated. However, A and B have may have common elements. The
>   following pseudo-code computes the number of common elements:
>
> ```
> count = 0
> for i from 0 to m:
>  if i < n:
>   for j from 0 to n:
>      if A[i]==B[j]:
>        count + =1
>        break
>  else:
>     break
> ```
>
> I seem to come up with the following complexities for the sort and comparison:
>
> bubble sort has worst O(n^2) and  best O(n)
>
> search has two bounds ( I think):  situation 1: no matches O(mn), 
>   situation 2: The first n elements of array A(size m) match to all of
>   the elements of array B(size n). -> O(n^2)
>
> Complexity possibilities (sort and search): O(n^2+mn),O(n+mn),O(n^2+n)=O(n^2) The best
>   seems to be sorted and no matches O(mn+n) The worst seems to be not
>   sorted and no matches O(n^2+mn) Does this seem valid?

Thank you.

P.S. sorry the whole thing is in block format. It would not let me submit without doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the arrays are sorted why you use binary search or `m:n` combinations comparison with it when you can done both operations in `O(n) <= O(n+m-c) <= O(n+m)` ?

Example how to do it for question 2:

```
int c=0; // common elements
for (int i=0,j=0;(i<m)&&(j<n);)
 {
      if (a[i]==b[i]) { c++; i++; j++; }
 else if (a[i]< b[i]) i++;
 else                   j++;
 }
```

- Just add some ifs for the end of arrays if needed (not sure if it will not ignore last common element and too lazy to analyze it) but anyway you see how to approach this kind of problems faster
- the same can be done with the comparison but you did not provide any details on its purpose ...

Now back to your questions:

1. if you parse each element of array `A` and bin-search relevant element in B for it

   - then yes worst complexity is `O(m.log(n))`
   - but the best also because you go through whole array of b without using last found index
   - btw if you would parse B and search A then `O(n.log(m))` is better if `m>n`
2. your code for common elements computation is confusing

   - why is there `if (i<n)` ???
   - what if you have `A={1,2,3,4,5}` and `B={3,5}` ?
   - then this if will reject both common elements
   - my opinion is that it should be removed
   - so after the removal the complexity is `O(m.n)` for all cases

**[edit1] code update to handle the edge case**

```
int c=0; // common elements
if (n+m) for (int i=0,j=0;;) // loop only if both arrays are not empty
 {
      if (a[i]==b[i]) { c++; if (i<m-1) i++; else if (j==n-1) break; j++;  }
 else if (a[i]< b[i]) {      if (i<m-1) i++; else if (j==n-1) break; }
 else                 {      if (j<n-1) j++; else if (i==m-1) break; }      
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Oh my bad, I do realize that if i <n causes an error. When you say perform both operation in O (n)< = O (n+m+c)... you mean just doing a linear search? And adding the if statements drops the time?. In addition why was my original way only O (mn)? I thought that if they are the same length and they are identical, then for the first element of the A it matches to the first element of B, 1 loop then the second elements match 2 loops + 3 ... so O (n^2) right? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @dylan7  1. `if`s will not drop (single iteration constant time) performance too much because they replaced for condition statement 2. because you got 2 nested `for`s in your code which will stop only on  duplicate elements so worst case O(m.n) ... 3. that is `O(n+m-c)` !!! the comparison is hard to determine without knowing how to compare ... and with what result

Comment: What if only the inner loop broke upon match found? Is that not what is happening?

Comment: @dylan7 `for (i ...)` gets you O(m), .... + nested for(j...) even with breaks gives you O(n.m) does not matter if it is breaking sometimes .... mostly it runs the full m cycles in your code... try to trace it then you will see what I mean (it is not obvious at first look) or add some counter inside to see how many cycles this really does